# How to create a playlist for audio associated with posts per category

Tags: posts, categories, audio

I am trying to find out how to create a playlist on the category page. The playlist will play all the songs/audio files associated with posts linked to a given category.

**Example**
If i have a category called "gospel", and 10 posts assigned to "gospel". Each post has a song associated with it. Hence , 10 total songs.

Goal is to have a playlist such that when i go to the category page for "gospel", i see a playlist that can play those 10 songs. As i add new posts and assign it to the category, it should also automatically sync and play it.

i appreciate any assistance

Answer (score 2):

1. get a 10 posts from category with slug "gospel"
2. get post children in loop, filter by mime type to get proper files
3. add to list

   ```
   /**
    * get 10 post from category with SLUG gospel
    */
   $args = array(
       'category_name' => 'gospel',
       'posts_per_page' => 10
   );
   $songs = array();
   $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
   if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
       while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
           $the_query->the_post();
           /**
            * get post children, filter by post_mime_type, limit 1
            */
           $args = array(
               'post_parent' => get_the_ID(),
               'post_type'   => 'attachment', 
               'posts_per_page' => 1,
               'post_status' => 'any',
               'post_mime_type' => 'audio'
           );
           $attachments = get_children( $args );
           if ( $attachments ) {
               foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                   $songs[] = wp_get_attachment_url( $attachment->ID);

               }
           }
       }
   }
   /**
    * print songs
    */
   print_r($songs);
   /**
    * reset postdata
    */
   wp_reset_postdata();
   ```